# How to detect uppercase and lowercase characters in a string using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and recently started learning about pointers.
I am trying to enter a string and then get the number of uppercase and lowercase characters in the string.
I want to do it with the help of pointers.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
    char s[20];
    int cu = 0, cl = 0, cs = 0;
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("\n%s", s);
    for (int *i = s; *i != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((*i >= 'A') && (*i <= 'Z'))
            cu++;
        else
        if ((*i >= 'a') && (*i <= 'z'))
            cl++;
        else
            cs++;
    }
    printf("\n uppercase:%d ,lowercase:%d ,others:%d", cu, cl, cs);
}
```

This is the output I get :

```
QWerTy12

QWerTy12
 uppercase:0 ,lowercase:0 ,others:3
```

As you can see, it's incorrect. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Didn't your compiler warn you that you are doing something dubious in `int *i=s`?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stop trouble-shooting bugs that the compiler has already found for you, by following this advice: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: In general, use `printf("%s\n", s);` rather than `printf("\n%s", s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, too much like [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76529202/2410359).  Saving as wiki,

---

**Key mistake: not compiling with all warnings enabled**

Will all warnings enabled, the problem is quickly identified:

```
char s[20];
...
for (int *i = s; *i != '\0'; i++) {
warning: initialization of 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Save time, enable all warnings and use consistent pointer types.

```
// for (int *i = s; *i != '\0'; i++) {
for (char *i = s; *i != '\0'; i++) {
```

Comment: Also `scanf("%s", s);` -> `if (scanf("%19s", s) != 1) return 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an `int *` pointer to access characters of a string. When you dereference the pointer it will read multiple characters (4 characters if `int` is 32 bits) and `i++` will increment by multiple characters.

You have to use `char *`, so change `int *i` to `char *i`.

Make sure you enable full warnings in your compiler options, and heed the warnings. When I tried to compile your code I got this warning:

```
testuplow.c:9:14: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'char[20]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    for(int *i=s;*i!='\0';i++)
             ^ ~
```